# use getter and setter in java LS2J

Tags: java, lotus-domino, ls2j

I have problem with the getter in LS2J, i can't have the result of the get in my prog !!
I take some tests, this is the results :

---

My class in java :

```
public String getFonctionWS() {

    System.out.println("get : " + fonctionWS);
    return fonctionWS;
}
public void setFonctionWS(String fonctionWS) {

    System.out.println("set : " + fonctionWS);
    this.fonctionWS = fonctionWS;
}
```

---

This same class called in LS2J :

```
Class LogWSDTO
sessionJava As JAVASESSION      
classJava As JAVACLASS
objectJava As JAVAOBJECT        
methodJava As JAVAMETHOD


Public Sub New()
    Set sessionJava = New JAVASESSION
    Set classJava = sessionJava.GetClass("com.pasquier.DTO.WS/LogWSDTO")
    Set objectJava = classJava.CreateObject     
End Sub

Public function getFonctionWS()
    Set methodJava = classJava.GetMethod("getFonctionWS","()Ljava/lang/String;")        
    getFonctionWS = objectJava.getFonctionWS        
End function
```

---

I call this class in lotus :

```
 Dim session As NotesSession


    logDTO.setFonctionWS("GetAllDocuments")         
    dt = logDTO.getFonctionWS
```

---

the result print : 
set : GetAllDocuments

Agent 'GetAllDocuments_LogWS GADBKWS' error: Wrong number of arguments for method

Sorry if i'm not very clear ^^ I have several problems and i was difficulty to explain one by one...
thanks for your help !

i begin to understand : in ls2j for get the getter, we must take a parameter ... !!!!(????)

when i try :

```
public String getEssai(String dt){
    System.out.println("get essai test20002");

    return fonctionWS;
}
```

it' fine, i have my result !!
i don't understand why but it works !!

could you explain me ??

Comment: That is way too much code. Reduce your issue to a **short** example which throws error too.

Comment: What is the question here? Get Set in Java. No there is no such thing!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786(v=vs.71).aspx This is for C# .. I don't think there would be any thing like that, you can ***however*** create your own constants and work with them!

Comment: i modified my explication

Comment: Please, create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. After your reduction it's definitely not Complete. Your example code have to be ready for copying into a test database and to show the issue you mentioned. Unfortunately, that is not the case so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be:

```
getFonctionWS = objectJava.getFonctionWS()
```